# Error Al Insertar Imagen En Base De Datos

Tags: c#

Llevo intentando varias formas de insertar una imagen en una base de datos Con Sql Server de diferentes métodos y ninguno a podido funcionar en la cual me manda unos errores, puedo almacenar datos tipos string y tipo int sin ningún problema pero no puedo guardar una imagen.

Error:

> Error relacionado con la red o específico de la instancia mientras se establecía una conexión con el servidor SQL Server. No se encontró el servidor o éste no estaba accesible. Compruebe que el nombre de la instancia es correcto y que SQL Server está configurado para admitir conexiones remotas. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - No se pudo abrir una conexión con SQL Server)

En Esta vez me guié utilizando los mismos pasos y `código` de este video
 [Sql Server Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BqyAAGMfTD8)

> Imagen Del Error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Codigo Completo

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=vsc; Initial Catalog=HRIS; User ID=sa; Password=vsc");
    SqlCommand command;
    string imgLoc = "";
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void buttonBrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
            dlg.Filter = "JPG Files (*.jpg)|*.jpg|GIF Files (*.gif)|*.gif|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
            dlg.Title = "Select Employee Picture";
            if(dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                imgLoc = dlg.FileName.ToString();
                picEmp.ImageLocation = imgLoc;  
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }                 

    }

    private void buttonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] img = null;
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(imgLoc, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
            img = br.ReadBytes((int)fs.Length);
            string sql = "INSERT INTO Employee(EID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,IMAGE)VALUES("+textBoxEID.Text+",'"+textBoxFName.Text+"','"+textBoxLName.Text+"',@img)";

            if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                conn.Open();
                command = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@img", img));
                int x = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();
                MessageBox.Show(x.ToString() + " record(s) saved.");
            }

            }

        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            conn.Close();
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Revisa bien tu connectionstring al parecer esta algo mal en ella

Comment: ¿Las credenciales de conexión a base de datos cambiaron en algún momento?

Comment: Si ponen referencias de otro foro, mínimo que este resuelto Davlio

Comment: Gracias por sus respuestas ya me fijare en eso y  lastima que fue marcado como duplicada por una pregunta totalmente diferente por personas ineficientes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple vista el tu connectionString
Intenta hacer esto en tu método constructor para validar que este bien:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    try
    {
       conn.Open();
       MessageBox.Show("Conexión establecida");
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
       MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Si te sale el mismo error entonces estaba en lo correcto